# Character do not get imported to MySQL Table from PHP using PHPExcel Reader

Tags: php, mysql, database

What is wrong with this code. Why not the character data from the array is being imported to the sql table.  My excel sheet contains mixture of character and integers which I have to import. I replaced every characters to some integer value in my excel sheet and checked and then I found that It is working fine but if it contains characters(alphabets) then it does not work. In the table also the column data-types are fine as they are Varchar.

I do not know why it is not able to import characters. If anyone has any clue or solution please reply back.

See this at Pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/q2KcUZBJ

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once 'excel_reader2.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("sample.xls");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("databaseName", $con);
$a=array("1"=>($data->val(1,'A')),"2"=>($data->val(1,'B')),"3"=>($data->val(1,'C')),"4"=> ($data->val(1,'D')),"5"=>($data->val(1,'E')),"6"=>($data->val(1,'F')),"7"=>($data->val(1,'G')));

$import="INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,col7) VALUES ($a[1],$a[2],$a[3],$a[4],$a[5],$a[6],$a[7])";
mysql_query($import) or die("mysql_error()");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because character (string) values must be quoted in your SQL Insert statement.

Updating to MySQLi or PDO where you can use prepared statements would resolve this issue, and remove your dependency on a deprecated MySQL interface

Comment: Thanks for the reply. will have to learn PDO.
so will preg_quote(); solve the issue for time being?

Comment: preg_quote will not do anything in this case, and shouldn't be used for this purpose because it's designed to escape regular expressions rather SQL queries. You need to identify the columns that are strings, and modify your SQL Insert statement accordingly (e.g. $a[2],'$a[3]',$a[4])

Comment: I used ('$a[1]',$a[2]...) and found that it works for only one character input. i.e, if I give('$a[1]','$a[2]',$a[3],$a[4],...) it stops working. It works fine if only one of the arguments is taking character .

Comment: Ensure that all string values are quoted, not just one. Put some diagnostics in your code - do a var_dump() of the $a, echo the SQL $import statement before executing your mysql query, etc. I can't see your spreadsheet, or your code as it is now, so I can't know what's happening, only guess.

Comment: Okay checked it. The problem is being caused by blank cells. MySQL is treating blank cell as string but I cannot say which of $a[] elements would be blank so I can't fix any particular element in $a[] as string coz in different rows different elements are blank. If I put all the elements as string then also it won't work as there are integers. Is there a way to treat blank cells as integers?

Comment: You'd need to "walk" your array explicitly setting the empty cells to integer 0.

Comment: Thanks @Mark I have finally finished correcting everything. I used this to convert empty cells to integer 0.

 for($j=1; $j<8; $j++){
  if($a[$j]=="")
 $a[$j] += 0;
 }

Answer (score 0):

check Database collation whether it is UTF-8.

Comment: The problem was characters not special characters. UTF-8 is only applicable for cases with special characters.